# Why is my button(id="closeDialogBtn") not working?

Tags: javascript, html, dialog

I want to use dialog element while update the the DOM.

When I try to update the DOM and open the dialog with the button containing Id="openDialogBtn". The dialog box is working fine(able to open), but the button with id="closeDialogBtn" isnot working while trying to close the dialog box.  Here's my code

```js
const openDialogBtn = document.getElementById("openDialogBtn");
const closeDialogBtn = document.getElementById("closeDialogBtn");
const dialogContainer = document.getElementById("dialogContainer");



openDialogBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialogContainer.innerHTML += `<p>Hello World</p>`
  dialogContainer.showModal();
})

closeDialogBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialogContainer.close();
  console.log("dialog closed")
})
```

```html
<button id="openDialogBtn">Open Dialog</button>
<dialog id="dialogContainer">
  <button id="closeDialogBtn">Close Dialog</button>
  <p>Dialog Content</p>
</dialog>
```

Comment: `dialogContainer.innerHTML += \`<p>Hello World</p>\`` - this will destroy and then re-create _all_ the elements inside the container, including your close button. Your old close button, that you bound a click handler to, has been replaced by a new one - but that new one doesn't have any click handler attached.

Comment: proof of what @CBroe wrote: https://jsfiddle.net/9gc6pka0/

Comment: if you want to use exploit event delegation: https://jsfiddle.net/v42unqek/

Answer (score 0):

```js
const openDialogBtn = document.getElementById("openDialogBtn");
const closeDialogBtn = document.getElementById("closeDialogBtn");
const dialogContainer = document.getElementById("dialogContainer");
//Using the same methods we grab that P so we can change data
const dialogContent = document.getElementById("dialogContent");


openDialogBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  //And Change from dialogContainer to dialogContent
  dialogContent.innerHTML += `<p>Hello World</p>`
  dialogContainer.showModal();
})

closeDialogBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  dialogContainer.close();
  console.log("dialog closed")
})
```

```html
<button id="openDialogBtn">Open Dialog</button>
<dialog id="dialogContainer">
  <button id="closeDialogBtn">Close Dialog</button>
  <p id="dialogContent">Dialog Content</p> 
  <!-- Added id for your P for where the new data will go -->
```

As @CBroe Commented your destroying your dialogs content and recreating them detaching the close buttons event. This method keeps your close button intact since we are only targeting a tag inside the Dialog.